# Run JunitCore.runClasses from Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, junit

I have two junit classes:

```
public class TestExample1 {

  @Test
  public void test() {
      System.out.println("running test1");
  }
}
```

and:

```
public class TestExample2 {

  @Test
  public void test() {
      System.out.println("running test2");
  }
}
```

I run this classes in Main:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestExample1.class, TestExample2.class);
        for(Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());

    }
}
```

How to run this code from Jenkins? Is there any possibility? For example using maven?

Answer (score 1):

You can run both of those tests just by calling `mvn test` in your terminal (assuming Maven is all set up and you're in the top directory of the project). Maven will pick up any test classes that match this pattern:

- `**/Test*.java`
- `**/*Test.java`
- `**/*Tests.java`
- `**/*TestCase.java`

Then you don't need the `Main` class at all.

Check out this link for more information using JUnit 5 with Maven: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

And this one for JUnit 4 and earlier: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html

If you prefer to use the `Main` class, you can use it in Maven with `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"`.

Docs for `mvn exec` here: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html